# Yeoman Angular Fullstack - how to secure routes?

Tags: angularjs, angular-fullstack

I have created a new route 'Rooms' with the generator and have modelled my $stateProvider on the admin route

```
.state('admin', {
    url: '/admin',
    templateUrl: 'app/admin/admin.html',
    controller: 'AdminController',
    controllerAs: 'admin',
    authenticate: 'admin'
  });
```

Vs

```
$stateProvider
  .state('rooms', {
    url: '/rooms',
    templateUrl: 'app/rooms/rooms.html',
    controller: 'RoomsCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'rooms',
    authenticate: 'admin'
  });
```

But my route still appears without authentication!

I guess I am missing a few things to make it secure, though I am unable to understand what!

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: check if you have an interceptor service factorie defined and called in your app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your controller should be like:

```
     angular.module('auth8App').controller('RoomsCtrl', function ($scope,Auth,$location) {

               //check if the user is logged-in
                Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
                        if (!loggedIn) {    
                       //if the user is not logged  Redirect to login
                          event.preventDefault();
                          $location.path('/login');
                        }
                      });
                    $scope.message = 'Hello';
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

check if you have an interceptor service factorie defined and called in your app.js lik this:

```
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
  })

  .factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $cookieStore, $location) {
    return {
      // Add authorization token to headers
      request: function (config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
          config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token');
        }
        return config;
      },

      // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
      responseError: function(response) {
        if(response.status === 401) {
          $location.path('/login');
          // remove any stale tokens
          $cookieStore.remove('token');
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
        else {
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
      }
    };
  })

  .run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
    // Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
      Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
        if (next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $location.path('/login');
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: now check whether the authentication middleware is called in your server endpoint

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Yes I have an authIntereptor [plunker](http://plnkr.co/nj5huWB1i5it7BIjfymL) ...

Comment: now check whether the authentication middleware is called in your server endpoint

Comment: looks like it : `/**
 

import errors from './components/errors';
import path from 'path';

module.exports = function(app) {

  // Insert routes below
  app.use('/api/things', require('./api/thing'));
  app.use('/api/users', require('./api/user'));

  app.use('/auth', require('./auth'));


  app.route('/:url(api|auth|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*')
   .get(errors[404]);

  
  app.route('/*')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html'));
    });
};`

Comment: ` 'use strict';


nothing much in here : angular.module('auth8App')
  .controller('RoomsCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.message = 'Hello';
  });
`

Comment: and rooms.js : `angular.module('auth8App')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('rooms', {
        url: '/rooms',
        templateUrl: 'app/rooms/rooms.html',
        controller: 'RoomsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'rooms',
        authenticate: 'admin'
      });
  });`

Comment: I get an error : TypeError: Auth.isLoggedIn(...).then is not a function
    at router.decorator.js:18?